# How to perfom_create when the objet is created in the admin site. Django RestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a perform_create for an object, which creates another object.

```
class DocumentDetailSampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DocumentDetailSample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentDetailSampleSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        doc_detail_sample = serializer.save()
        query_set = User.objects.all()
        ids = query_set.values_list('id', flat=True)
        for i in ids:
            doc_detail = DocumentDetail()
            doc_detail.details_sample = doc_detail_sample
            doc_detail.user_id_id = str(i)
            doc_detail.save()
```

As you can see, when I create a `DocumentDetailSample` a `DocumentDetail` is also created.

It works nicely when I make a "POST".

My problem is that `DocumentDetailSamples` can also be created in the Admin Site. So... When it's created in the Admin site, the `perform_create` doesn't work anymore and the `DocumentDetail` is not created.

What could I do? I want to create the `DocumentDetail` also right after the "admin" `DocumentDetailSample` creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals are a useful tool for this job ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/))

Using the `post_save` signal you can run a function every time an instance of a model is saved, no matter where it is saved from. The `post_save` signal provides the created argument so you only run the function when the object is created

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import DocumentDetailSample


@receiver(post_save, sender=DocumentDetailSample)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        query_set = User.objects.all()
        ids = query_set.values_list('id', flat=True)
        for i in ids:
            doc_detail = DocumentDetail()
            doc_detail.details_sample = kwargs['instance']
            doc_detail.user_id_id = str(i)
            doc_detail.save()
```

Comment: thanks! Where should I write that function? In the views.py? And also, you import "post_save" and then you use "pre_save" in the receiver. Which is the right one? :)

Comment: NICE!!! Thanks!!! :) 
So, yeah, I wrote it in the views.py and it's post_save. _pre_save_ doesn't have a 'created' :) Thanks!